# Remove subjects if they don't have both waves of data

Tags: r

I have a dataset in long format with a column titled subject and wave.

Each subject has up to two rows (one for wave 1 and one for wave 2). If they are missing a wave, then they only have one row.

I only want to keep subjects in the dataset if they have both wave 1 and wave 2 data.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Using `dplyr` you can do `data %>% group_by(subject) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% filter(count > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to remove non duplicated subjects.

```
subset(data,duplicated(variable) | duplicated(data, fromLast=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  add_count(subject) %>% 
  filter(n == 2)
```